# Form submission works in Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: reactjs, forms, google-chrome, firefox

I have a form submission that works on Chrome but not on Firefox. When I do submit it on Chrome, the React component reloads correctly, showing the new name added. But when I do it in Firefox, nothing happens.

Any help would be amazing, thanks!

```
function handleSubmit(event){
        axios.post('/api/addname', {name})
    }
```

```
  function handleOnChange(event){
        if (event.target.name === 'name'){
            setName(event.target.value);
        };
    };
```

```
 return (
      <div>   
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input onChange={handleOnChange} placeholder="New name" name="name" value={name}/> ()
            <input type='submit' value='Add name'/>
        </form>
      </div>
  )
```

Comment: is there any console errors? We need more info

Comment: Yes, there's a console error that says Uncaught (in promise)